# How do I "Take Source Branch Version" for all conflicts in TFS 2008 on Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs

The closest thing I see to what I want is "AutoResolve All".  I don't want to AutoMerge though.

In Visual Studio 2008 I could say I wanted to have the source override on all or the target on all.

Where is this option in 2010?  Did they take it away?  It looks like my only option is to click "Take Source Branch Version" on all 70 files one by one.

Comment: That (Q+A) still applies to Visual Studio 2015 ...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check out the TF.EXE command [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yw3tcdy%28VS.100%29.aspx).

`tf.exe resolve ..... /auto:TakeTheirs` will "Take Source Branch Version."  My suggestion is to do the resolve, then check your branch and make sure that you have what you expect before you check in.

`tf.exe resolve .... /auto:KeepTheirs` will "Keep Target Branch Version"

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't think about using the command prompt stuff.  I wish this was one of the buttons on the IDE!

Comment: The command line names ("TakeTheirs" and "KeepTheirs") drive me nuts.........not sure how "TakeSource" and "KeepTarget" didn't make it ..

Comment: @granadaCoder Probably that the team that developed the command line utility did it because the front end was so limited, then MS decided to bundle it since it was so useful, hence the use of weird alternative names.

Answer (score 45):

Select all and click Take Source Version.Note ctrl+A doesn't work. So select the first item, hold shift and select the last item.

[image: In the Resolve conflicts window]

Comment: The shift click was the key! Odd that ctrl+a doesn't work on this particular list but shift clicking does.

Comment: Nice. This also works when you have conflicts and need to apply "Keep Local Version" to all items. In my case it was over 2500 files due to a code migration. Saved me many clicks.

Comment: In **Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise** I was able to use **CTRL+a** to select all. Then, proceed as described (after selecting all, click "Take Source Version"). It will be applied to all items.

Comment: This does not work in Visual Studio 2013. (OK in 2015)

Comment: Omg, this is a lifesaver, I've been doing it individually ever since, until this time I'm tired and I want it to be resolved now.

Comment: Thanks buddy! You saved me from 1693 clicks.